# Codeigniter Referral Segment

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm currently struggling with finding a way to extract a segment from the referrer URL using CodeIgniter.

As for normal url segment can be found by

```
$this->uri->segment(n)
```

where n is the number of section we are looking for.

My intuition says I should use the following, but of course it's not working.

```
$this->agent->referrer()->segment(1);
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Would you please format your code fragment properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The referrer function in Codeigniter doesn't allow for a segment - it simply returns the `$_SERVER` parameter (Found in User_agent.php):

```
public function referrer()
{
    return empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? '' : trim($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}
```

You will therefore need to explode the URL or use http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php to get the elements for you.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can  get reffer URI using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, and then `parse_url` to get the path from the URL and then use `explode` to split it into its segments.

Example:

```
$from = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$segments = explode('/', $from['path']);

//result
$first_segment = $segments[0];
$second_segment = $segments[1];
$third_segment = $segments[3];
// and more

//but if you want to count start from last segment example is below

$first_segment_from_last = $segments[sizeof($segments)-1];
$second_segment_from_last = $segments[sizeof($segments)-2];
//and more

//test
print_r('my refferal URI is ' . $from . ', and the first segment is '. $first_segment);
```